# Django pass variable to Python script

Tags: python, django

I have a Django app, with 2 pages: `index.html` and `device_list.html`

Index page:

```
    <div class="search">
        <form action="" method="POST">
            {% csrf_token %}
            {{ form.as_p }}
            <input type="text" class="input" name="UserInput"> 
        </form>           
    </div>

    <div class="btn">
        <button class="btns" onclick="location.href='{% url 'script' %}'">Generate</button>
    </div>
</div>
```

here is device_list.html page:

```
{% extends "base.html" %}

{% block content %}

{{output}}

{% endblock content %}
```

Views.py:

```
def index(request):
    return render(request, 'index.html')

def device_list(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = SiteCodeForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
        command = ["python","run.py","VARIABLE" ]
        process = Popen(command, stdout=PIPE, stderr=STDOUT)
        output = process.stdout.read()
        print(output)
        json_str = json.dumps({'message': output.decode('utf-8')})

        return HttpResponse(json.dumps(json_str), content_type='application/json', status=200)
        ----- IM STUCK HERE -----
```

So I don't know how to proceed, and pass the variable from index page to the python script that I have in views. It actually runs the script, and I can see the result in the terminal, but the output won't show up in the device_list.html - it's empty.

Comment: Show us how you're rendering the device_list html template.

Comment: Just updated the post

Comment: That view does not render the device_list template at all.  So I'm confused what is your question?

Comment: Are you trying to get to `device_list ` view upon the form submission on `index` view?

Answer (score 1):

To display the *output* in your *device_list.html* you must pass it to context to be rendered in the template.

You can try this way:

views.py

```
from django.template.response import TemplateResponse
...

def device_list(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = SiteCodeForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
        command = ["python","run.py","VARIABLE" ]
        process = Popen(command, stdout=PIPE, stderr=STDOUT)
        output = process.stdout.read()
        print(output)
        json_str = json.dumps({'message': output.decode('utf-8')})
        context = {
            'json_str': json_str,
            'output': output
        }
        return TemplateResponse(request, 'device_list.html', context)
```

You can use also use *render* method the same way like `return render(request, 'template_name', context)`. See the documentation [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/ref/forms/renderers/#the-low-level-render-api)

More details about [Template Response](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/ref/template-response/) use.